# XPath exclude text from last element if it meets condition

Tags: r, xpath

The goal is to exclude text if it is contained in the last element within the tags <*p*><*em*>...<*/em*><*/p*>.

```
...
<p>"We are a better country because of these commitments," he said. "I'll go further – we would not be a great country without [them]."</p>
<p>Liberals were mostly delighted by what the <em>Washington Post</em> called "the most ambitious defence [Obama] may ever have attempted of American liberalism and of what it means to be a Democrat".</p>
<p>This was the Obama many of them hoped for when they voted him into office on that wave of enthusiasm back in 2008.</p>
<p><em>Felicity Spector is a deputy programme editor for <a href="http://www.channel4.com/news/" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href);return false;">Channel 4 News</a></em>.</p>
```

The output should be:

```
"We are a better country because of these commitments," he said. "I'll go further – we would not be a great country without [them]."
Liberals were mostly delighted by what the Washington Post called "the most ambitious defence [Obama] may ever have attempted of American liberalism and of what it means to be a Democrat".
This was the Obama many of them hoped for when they voted him into office on that wave of enthusiasm back in 2008.
```

So, need to grab everything excluding the text if it is located in the last <*p*> tag and there is no other text between <*p*> and <*em*> tags as well as no other text between <*/em*> and <*/p*> as illustrated in example above.

I m using

```
//p[normalize-space()]
```

but it returns eveerything including the text from the last tag <*p*><*em*>...<*/em*>:

```
"We are a better country because of these commitments," he said. "I'll go further – we would not be a great country without [them]."
Liberals were mostly delighted by what the Washington Post called "the most ambitious defence [Obama] may ever have attempted of American liberalism and of what it means to be a Democrat".
This was the Obama many of them hoped for when they voted him into office on that wave of enthusiasm back in 2008.
Felicity Spector is a deputy programme editor for Channel 4 News
```

while the last sentance should be excluded.

Appreciate for any hints.

**UPD**

**Example 1.** The next text should be returned if it is located in last <*p*> (since not all the text is inside <*em*>:

```
<p>I was once on a travelling sanitation carnival in Uttar Pradesh when someone rushed up to me. “Rose! Rose! There’s a real ‘no loo no I do’!” If that’s the story of <em>Ek Prem Katha</em>, then I’m all in favour.  But because bringing a toilet into the world, when there are still 2.4 billion people without one, is by any reckoning a very happy ending.</p>
```

**Example 2.** The next text should **not** be returned if it is located in last <*p*> (because all the text in inside <*em*>):

```
<p><em>Sophie Elmhirst is an assistant editor of the NS</em></p>
```

Comment: since you have the R tag, is there R code you need help with?

Comment: `(//p)[not(position()=last() and em)]`

Comment: Please show a complete HTML document that includes all the variability you have to deal with. Obviously, some of the `p` elements are empty (the only reason why you would have the `normalize-space()` predicate) for example. Are all `p` elements siblings, i.e. is it a flat structure? How about the last `p` element if it does not contain `em`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller, the structure is exactly as it is given there. The last `p` not always contain `em`. i need to exclude text from the last `p` only if the whole text surrounded within `em`. Maybe `normalize-space` isn't required but I always use it.

Comment: @splash58, did'nt you miss **following::**? Maybe you mean smth like:  `(//p)[not(position()=last() and following::em)]` ?

Comment: @Alex I understood that em - child of p.

Comment: @splash58 that's correct, `em` is inside `p`

Comment: @Alex then `following` will be incorrect. You may write `child::` but that is the same i wrote

Comment: @splash58 right, that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unclear what exactly the rules are, but here is a suggestion that you can comment on:

```
//p[normalize-space() and not(position() = last() and em)]
```

which translates to

```
//p                           find all `p` elements anywhere in the document
[normalize-space()            but only if the contain at least 1 character that is not a white-space
and not(position() = last()   and only if the `p` element is not the last `p` child of its parent
and em)]                      and only if the `p` element has no child named `em`
```

and returns as a result (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
<p>"We are a better country because of these commitments," he said. "I'll go further – we would not be a great country without [them]."</p>
-----------------------
<p>Liberals were mostly delighted by what the <em>Washington Post</em> called "the most ambitious defence [Obama] may ever have attempted of American liberalism and of what it means to be a Democrat".</p>
-----------------------
<p>This was the Obama many of them hoped for when they voted him into office on that wave of enthusiasm back in 2008.</p>
```

Caveat: if the structure of your document is actually more complex this might go wrong in places, for example when `p` elements can occur anywhere in the hierarchy.

---

> Maybe normalize-space isn't required but I always use it.

Only use it if you really want to exclude elements that have only whitespace in them.

> i need to exclude text from the last p only if the whole text surrounded within em

Well, in your own example of a last `p` element with `em` in it that's not the case: the last `.` is actually outside of `em`, it's a text node of `p`.

---

**EDIT** Reacting to a comment:

> I just figured out that the xpath doesn't return text if there is a text outside the em in last p. I have updated an example

Then use the path expression below:

```
//p[normalize-space() and not(position() = last() and em and not(text()))]
```

Sorry, I might have misunderstood you until now. The `not(text())` takes into account whether there is text which is a child of `p` itself, outside of `em`.

Comment: you are right regarding the dot (`.`) which is outside the `em` in last node in my example. I tried the xpath `//p[normalize-space() and not(position() = last() and em)]` and it looks like it doesn't return the text if the dot (.) is outside. Is that the right behavior for such xpath ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's correct. So, what are the rules exactly? a ) Only return the  `p` element in the last position which has an `em` child element if _all_ the text content is inside this `em` or b) also return it if some of the text is outside of `em`. Which one is true for you?

Comment: yes, the b) option is correct. However, symbols like `[?!,.:"]` etc may be located outside the `em`

Comment: I just figured out that the xpath doesn't return text if there is a text outside the `em` in last `p`. I have updated an example.